# How can i use setect2 4.0 click x and don't show dropdown box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 4.0 ,when i click x(delete button),it clear the selete box,and show the dropdown box,but i dont't want show it ,how to do this?

Comment: [This Select2 ticket is relevant](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3320), but it's not an issue that will be fixed in the upcoming 4.0.1 release.